# Create drop-down list in Excel from Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a simple list and add value to it from Access using Access VBA and export the data to Excel.

I figured out exporting data to Excel.

I searched the net but not able to create the drop-down list.

Comment: Can you please refrase your question, it is unclear. Especialy "... after from ACCESS using access vba ..." what do you mean by that?

Comment: I am using access VBA to export data to Excel.. I  after exporting the data to excel, I need to set column B as validation list.  How do I create the validation list using access VBA after exporting the data to excel.. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code ? What did you do so far ?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. You wish to use Access VBA to modify the exported Excel file. After the file is created, and the data exported to it from Access, you wish to modify the formatting of cells & columns to include a dropdown box..?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a form,
 
Take a combobox control and a command button
Then put following code to command button `Click Event`.

```
Private Sub cmdAddtoCombo_Click()
 Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        cboItems.AddItem "Item - " & i
    Next i

End Sub
```

> Combobox `Row Source Type` should be `Value List`

[image]